# Swift, Tableview Constraints Not Behaving Normally - Xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, autolayout

I have a simple to do list app and would like to set constraints for each custom table view cell in the storyboard.

I have an image view on the left, the main label in the middle and a time on the right.

In this image, the labels and text view should be arranged like this

[image]

However, when I add constraints which seem correct, the actual app looks like this:

[image]

I'm not sure what is happening and if anyone could tell me which constraints to add, then that would be greatly appreciated. I am also going to make the cells resize to fit more content

Thanks :)

Comment: Please make those images smaller.

Comment: It would be helpful to see a screenshot of the constraints to see where you are going wrong with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way you can do it is by putting all your elements into horizontal `UIStackView`. Take a look at the **ThirdCell** on the image below.

These are the three key points in this solution.

- Set the constant width to the left side `UIView`. It may not be necessary if you use `UIImage`.
- Set the horizontal content hugging priority of the right `UILabel` to required (1000).
- Set the number of lines in the middle `UILabel` to 0.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Sample Result**

[image: Sample Result]

**Layout**
You want the cell contain image -> label -> label

So:

**1. image constraint align left** (left:0, top:0, bottom:0, width:5)
   [image: Left image constraints]
**2. right label constraint align right** (right:8, top:0, bottom:0, width:50)
   and label text align center & right.
   [image: Right label constraint]
**3. middle label take up the remaining space.**
   [image: Middle label constraint]

Answer (score 0):

Look on your view hierarchy and understand where you made it wrong. You should run project and press it (red arrow) https://tppr.me/v2ODz

If you understand now what is problem other typical to it issues you will be able to solve by yourself